# Django filters - I want to sort the previous query and not the entire model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

When I filter the table by city, for example, it works;
but if I want to sort by date or price using the multiple choices menu, django-filter sorts the entire model by the selected value and not only the cities.
How can I fix this problem?

```
import django_filters
from django_filters import DateFilter
from .models import ModelName
 
class SortFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
 
    SORT_BY_DATE_AND_PRICE = (
        ('date_asc', 'Date ascending'),
        ('date_desc', 'Date descending'),
        ('price_asc', 'Price ascending'),
        ('price_desc', 'Price descending')
    )
 
    sort = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(label='Order by:', choices=SORT_BY_DATE_AND_PRICE, method='filter_by_date_and_price')
 
    class Meta:
        model = ModelName
        fields = ['city', 'destination']
 
    def filter_by_date_and_price(self, queryset, name, value):
        if value == 'date_asc':
            sort = 'date'
        elif value == 'date_desc':
            sort = '-date'
        elif value == 'price_asc':
            sort = 'price'
        elif value == 'pret_desc':
            sort = '-price'
 
        return queryset.order_by(sort)
```

Answer (score 0):

Entry.objects.filter(value="Value").filter(another_value="Another value")

Comment: You can specify more by using a dot after the filtered objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this. I was going to leave it as a comment but I'm writing to answer because my rep score is not enough.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-Rct7Na0UQ